# Making HTML content expand to fill the window

Tags: html, css, noscript

I have an HTML page divided vertically into

- Header
- Body
- Footer

The body in turn is divided horizontally into

- A large DIV on the left surrounded by scrollbars, displaying a portion of a diagram
- A form on the right

The header and footer are fixed-height.  The body should expand vertically to fill the portion of the window not occupied by the header and footer.

Similarly the form is fixed-width and the scroll pane should expand horizontally to fill the window width.

The diagram is very large (up to 10x10 screenfuls) so I cannot display all of it.  Instead I want to display as much as possible (using the whole window) so that the user needs to scroll as little as possible.

I also cannot use javascript, because some users are necessarily paranoid and must disable it.

Some options I have considered:

- A table with the scroll pane cell's width and height set to 100% and all others to 1%

  *Doesn't work.  The table (and hence the page) expands to contain the entire diagram, even with absolute positioning on the scroll pane DIV.*
- Absolute positioning to offset the pane from the bottom of the page by the height of the footer
  *Works but inaccurate: the footer's height depends on the current font size and whether text is wrapped.  This means I must leave a large margin to ensure they do not overlap.*
- Place the diagram in an IFRAME
  *The best solution I've found with scripts disabled, but limits what I can do in scripts when they **are** enabled.*

I notice that Google Maps uses a fixed-size area for the map when scripts are disabled.  If Google has given up on this problem does that mean it's not feasible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the height: 100% CSS attribute should make it work.

See if [Dave Woods 100% Height Layout Using CSS](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=144) works for you.

Comment: Part of this is useful - I didn't know you could put width and height on the style of the <HTML> element - I was wrapping everything in a top-level DIV with absolute positioning.  Now I just need a way to say "give the header/footer/form their minimum space and give all the rest to the scroll pane".

Answer (score 4):

It's a little known aspect of the `position: absolute;` CSS property that will give you the layout you are looking for. You can absolutely position an element in ALL 4 directions, top, right, bottom and left. This means a box can be as fluid as the browser and always remain the same distance away from the edges of it's container that you specify.

```
div {
    position: absolute;
}
#main {
    top: 8em; // 8em
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 8em; // 8em
    right: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#header {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 8em;
}
#sidebar {
    top: 8em;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 8em;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 8em;
}
```

For an example check out http://www.sanchothefat.com/dev/layouts/cssframes.html and then view source and pull apart the CSS to see how it's done in a more complex example.

**If you take this approach you have to absolutely position ALL the main container `<div>`s. Use ems if font-size is a concern.**

PS. There is a gotcha in that IE6 messes up (shock!) however the example I have provided has an IE6 fallback. Just a fixed height will be fine though.

Comment: I think this is the same as my option #2

Comment: yeah sorry i didn't quite follow at first, editing my answer to suit better

Comment: I think it's your best option as you state your header and footer are fixed height. Otherwise if you don't want to use javascript you'll have to use a fixed height area for the diagram.