# CSS: Set Div height to 100% - Pixels

Tags: css, html, height

I have a header on my page which is just over 100px (111px to be exact)
The div below it needs to extend to the bottom of the viewport, as if i had set the bottom to 0px. The problem lies in the fact that i cannot specify top and bottom in ie6 (bug).

I can either specify top: 111px or bottom: 0px, but i still need the height to be correct ie. 100% -111px, according to the size of the viewport.

Can't seem to get expressions working coz that seems to be the solution

Here's my css code:

```
position: absolute; 
width: 200px; 
top: 111px; 
bottom: 0px;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make div 100% height of browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Answer (score 27):

The best way to do this is to use view port styles. It just does the work and no other techniques needed.

Code:

```css
div{
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: As usual, needs a word of caution when using in IE. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 22):

I added the **height** property to the *body* and *html* tags.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header">header</div>
 <div id="content">content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrapper
{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#header
{
    height: 111px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can just use `position:absolute`:

```
#content
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 111px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

However, IE6 doesn't like top and bottom declarations. But web developers don't like IE6.

Comment: thats exactly what i had, and as you have mentioned IE6 doesn't like both used at the same time. I agree with you, but thats how the client wants it. had to write javascript to get it right

Comment: `top` and `bottom` multiple position declarations don't work on *any* browser

Comment: many apologies! You're right.  And I did a quick test without `position: absolute`. My vote's locked in, darnit. Someone upvote this guy and correct my evil ways :)

Answer (score 6):

```css
div{
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't apply to all browsers

Answer (score 5):

Now with css3 you could try to use calc()

```
.main{
  height: calc(100% - 111px);
}
```

have a look at this answer:
[Div width 100% minus fixed amount of pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651317/div-width-100-minus-fixed-amount-of-pixels#answer-14685747)

Answer (score 5):

```css
div{
  height:100vh;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are trying to get [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Comment: hmm not exactly that but sort of along those lines. i have a header so i adjusted the css accordingly but the div is too big, still getting set to 100%

Answer (score 0):

Negative margins of course!

#### HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header Text</h1>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur 
        ullamcorper velit aliquam dolor dapibus interdum sed in dolor. Phasellus 
        vel quam et quam congue sodales.
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#header
{
    height: 111px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#wrapper
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: -111px;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
#content
{
    margin-top: 111px;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

100vh works for me, but at first I had used javascript (actually jQuery, but you can adapt it), to tackle a similar problw.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

js/jQuery

```
var innerWindowHeight = $(window).height();
var headerHeight = $("#header").height();
var contentHeight = innerWindowHeight - headerHeight;
$(".content").height(contentHeight + "px");
```

Alternately, you can just use 111px if you don't want to calculate headerHeight.

Also, you may want to put this in a window resize event, to rerun the script if the window height increases for example.