# How to make a div 100% height of the browser window

Tags: html, css, height

I have a layout with two columns - a left `div` and a right `div`.

The right `div` has a grey `background-color`, and I need it to expand vertically depending on the height of the user's browser window. Right now, the `background-color` ends at the last piece of content in that `div`.

I've tried `height:100%`, `min-height:100%;`, etc.

Comment: May you'll find this question usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366548/css-set-div-height-to-100-pixels

Comment: Good way to go, but vh, vw etc units are known to be buggy. There's this lightweight js alternative if you need it: http://joaocunha.github.io/vunit/

Comment: Here's a simple and clear explanation of the CSS `height` property with percentage values: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: way out there in 2024 but couldn't you use view heights now? just make sure to set all height properties: `min-height:100vh; height:100vh; max-height:100vh;`

Answer (score 3306):

There are a couple of CSS 3 measurement units called:

#### [Viewport-Percentage *(or Viewport-Relative)* Lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

##### What are Viewport-Percentage Lengths?

From the linked W3 Candidate Recommendation above:

> *The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.*

These units are `vh` (viewport height), `vw` (viewport width), `vmin` (viewport minimum length) and `vmax` (viewport maximum length).

##### How can this be used to make a divider fill the height of the browser?

For this question, we can make use of `vh`: `1vh` is equal to 1% of the viewport's height. That is to say, `100vh` is equal to the height of the browser window, regardless of where the element is situated in the DOM tree:

###### HTML

```html
<div></div>
```

###### CSS

```css
div {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

This is literally all that's needed. Here is a [**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/hr8sL/) of this in use.

##### What browsers support these new units?

This is currently supported on all up-to-date major browsers apart from Opera Mini. Check out [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) for further support.

##### How can this be used with multiple columns?

In the case of the question at hand, featuring a left and a right divider, here is a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/hr8sL/1/) showing a two-column layout involving both `vh` and `vw`.

##### How is `100vh` different from `100%`?

Take this layout for example:

```html
<body style="height: 100%">
    <div style="height: 200px">
        <p style="height: 100%; display: block;">Hello, world!</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

The `p` tag here is set to 100% height, but because its containing `div` has 200 pixels height, 100% of 200 pixels becomes 200 pixels, *not* 100% of the `body` height. Using `100vh` instead means that the `p` tag will be 100% height of the `body` regardless of the `div` height. Take a look at this [accompanying JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/hr8sL/2/) to easily see the difference!

Comment: Strange behavior with scrolling when the element is actually taller than the viewport. The container maintains the viewport height and the content flows out of the container. `min-height:100vh` seems to work around this.

Comment: Viewport-Percentage don't have nearly enough support in order to be used in a production environment. You have to write a fallback every time which ends up creating more of a mess than if you had simply not used VP.

Comment: @DGDD following on: there are plenty of other solutions here which work as far back as IE5, so there was no need for me to repeat what others have already said. This answer is solid enough for the majority of browsers released in the last 3 years since the spec was first introduced.

Comment: Actually I was referring to mobiles which VPs are not supported on. With the amount of users that use mobiles (30% +), I think ignoring over a third of users can be considered a non-functioning answer.

Comment: @DGDD this works on iOS Safari 6+, Android Browser 4.4+, BlackBerry Browser 10.0 and IEMobile 10.0. I don't know which mobile browser you're refering to, but those 4 make up over 90% of mobile browsers used. This question doesn't specify a requirement for working on mobile browsers.

Comment: Okay, but the answer is still very myopic and only works in extremely limited situations.  Flexbox CSS (http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/) would cover this answer and more.

Comment: @robross0606 again that is not the question I've answered here. That's a different question altogether, whose answer does indeed use flexbox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space

Comment: you need to see this http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units and than make desigion

Comment: @DanielRodriguez according to [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh) it works on all up-to-date mobile browsers except Opera Mini.

Comment: You should also set `body { margin: 0 }` because even in case of `box-sizing: border-box`, margin is not included in measurement.

Comment: VH isn't equal browser window height. It's viewport height.

Comment: @Soaku the viewport height is equal to the height of the region (viewport) the website displays in within a web browser. That's what I meant by "the height of the browser window", in much more basic terms.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yes, I know. But that's not the answer to this question. Browser window height includes the navbar height. This would be better, because on mobile browsers, viewport height changes every time the navbar shows/hides.

Comment: Mobile alert: using vh mess with Chrome mobile which doesn't take into account its navbar. It then cover the top of your page with it. A serious issue if you have a menu there...

Comment: @Langdon, using `box-sizing: border-box` would help to avoid including `border` and `paddings` to `height` and `width`. [About box sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Holy grail! you saved my day.. I was trying to apply gradient to the whole background and i saw a split at a certain height. After setting height to 100vh, its looking great

Comment: Incredibly useful! Allowed me to scrap many lines of JS and easily make a header with a min height for mobile, max height for desktop, and auto-adjusting range of heights in between for tablets, all with just a few simple declarations: `#header {height: 20vw; min-height: 64px; max-height: 128px; transition: 0.4s;}`

Comment: Wow I have been out of the front end UI game for a while. I didnt realize vh was a thing. This makes it quite easier than the hacks used back in the day.

Comment: Why have I not known about this yet.

Comment: As Offirmo mentioned, this does not take into account the top navbar. What is the workaround for that?

Answer (score 616):

If you want to set the height of a `<div>` or any element, you should set the height of `<body>` and `<html>` to 100% too. Then you can set the height of element with 100% :)

Here is an example:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#right {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, But i think you also need to set the height to all the parents of the div, to actually work

Comment: This won't work if I am using continuing design: page 6000px height, with blocks representing pages. I want one block to be exactly the viewport's height.

Comment: @DanyY, you are right. You do need to set the height to all the parents of the div, with the implications of everything having the height of the screen. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/f6WXR/).

Comment: This trick work for some cases but it wouldn't for some cases too, If you search for compatibility or more recommended way, you can view @James's Answer above :)

Using Viewport Percentage Method :) , That's should work too. cheers

Comment: @Qwerty, here's the solution. Set css as so: `html { height: 100%*number of blocks; }`, `body { height: 100%;}`, `#div { height: 100%/number of blocks; }`. So if you have 3 sections, it will be `html { height: 300%; } body { height: 100%; } #div { height: 33.3% }`

Comment: @DanyY, in addition to the steps mentioned in the answer, make a div with a class of `.body` and make its position `absolute`, then give this div a `height` of `100%` and `width` of `100%`, finally, don't forget to `bottom: 0` and `right: 0`. after that, whenever you need a full screen you can use this `.body`

Answer (score 315):

If you’re able to absolutely position your elements,

```css
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

would do it.

Comment: This works by taking the element out of the document flow and cementing its bottom value to the height of its parent. This is not ideal when your content exceeds the height of its parent.

Comment: That does not work, when one of it's parents is set to `position:relative` and its height is not 100% of the viewport. It will adjust top and bottom to it's next relative or absolute ancestor.

Answer (score 151):

You can use the view-port unit in CSS:

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="my-div">Hello World!</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#my-div {
    height: 100vh; /* vh stands for view-port height, and 1vh is 1% of screen height */
}
```

Comment: @Lamar You should use `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Worth checking caniuse for browser support on viewport units: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 145):

You can use `vh` in this case which is relative to **1% of the height** of the viewport...

That means if you want to cover off the height, just simply use `100vh`.

Look at the image below I draw for you here:

[image: How to make a div 100% height of the browser window?]

Try the snippet I created for you as below:

```css
.left {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Comment: Giving 100vh added a vertical scroll for the page , so followed this one but didnt worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645465/when-using-height-100vh-for-the-container-vertical-scrollbar-appears.  Is there any way to avoid the vertical scroll and have the div touches the bottom without any content ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS look for existing `paddings/margins`

Comment: @Legends at the root file i tried giving as * 
{margin: 0, padding: 0} but didnt worked

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS take a look at this example here provided by Alireza, it also has a scrollbar because the body element has a margin. If you remove the margin the scrollbar is gone. It can have different causes, but this one I would checkout first.

Answer (score 124):

All the other solutions, including the top-voted one with `vh` are sub-optimal when compared to the [flex model](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) solution.

With the advent of the [CSS flex model](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/), solving the 100% height problem becomes very, very easy: use `height: 100%; display: flex` on the parent, and `flex: 1` on the child elements. They'll automatically take up all the available space in their container.

Note how simple the markup and the CSS are. No table hacks or anything.

The flex model is [supported by all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) as well as IE11+.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  background: orange;
}

.right {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
```

Learn more about the [flex model](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) here.

Comment: a word of warning: when the content of one of the left/right containers exceeds the original body height, the opposite container won't get resized, so the containers end up with different heights then.

Comment: Example of the problem Schellmax points out: https://jsfiddle.net/Arete/b4g0o3pq/

Comment: Depending on the design, `overflow-y: auto;` may avoid "containers exceeds the original body height".

Comment: the `body` also needs `margin: 0px`

Answer (score 56):

You don't mention a few important details like:

- Is the layout fixed width?
- Are either or both of the columns fixed width?

Here's one possibility:

```css
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
#wrapper,
#left,
#right {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 960px; /* Width optional */
}

#left {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
  width: 360px; /* Width optional, but recommended */
}

#right {
  background: grey;
  margin-left: 360px; /* Must agree with previous width */
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
      Left
    </div>

    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

There are many variations on this depending on which columns need to be fixed and which are liquid. You can do this with absolute positioning too but I've generally found better results (particularly in terms of cross-browser) using floats instead.

Answer (score 43):

This is what worked for me:

```html
<div style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; background: red;"> </div>
```

Use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`, that way even if you scroll down the division will expand to the end of the screen.

Comment: This code with the "position: [ fixed | absolute]" is great for the backgrounds of popups (like when you click to zoom a picture) but not so sure in the cases when you need to actually scroll down. Still useful dough!

Answer (score 31):

Here's a fix for the height.

In your CSS use:

```css
#your-object: height: 100vh;
```

For browser that don't support `vh-units`, use modernizr.

Add this script (to add detection for `vh-units`)

```javascript
// https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/572
// Similar to http://jsfiddle.net/FWeinb/etnYC/
Modernizr.addTest('cssvhunit', function() {
    var bool;
    Modernizr.testStyles("#modernizr { height: 50vh; }", function(elem, rule) {
        var height = parseInt(window.innerHeight/2, 10),
            compStyle = parseInt((window.getComputedStyle ?
                      getComputedStyle(elem, null) :
                      elem.currentStyle)["height"], 10);

        bool = !!(compStyle == height);
    });
    return bool;
});
```

Finally use this function to add the height of the viewport to `#your-object` if the browser doesn't support `vh-units`:

```javascript
$(function() {
    if (!Modernizr.cssvhunit) {
        var windowH = $(window).height();
        $('#your-object').css({'height':($(window).height()) + 'px'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 29):

100vw = 100% of the width of the viewport.

100vh = 100% of the height of the viewport.

If you want to set the `div` width or height 100% of browser-window-size you should use:

For width: `100vw`

For height: `100vh`

Or if you want to set it smaller size, use the CSS `calc` function. Example:

```css
#example {
    width: calc(100vw - 32px)
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Even with all of the answers here, I was surprised to find that none really solved the problem.  If I used `100vh` `height`/`min-height`, the layout broke when the content was longer than a page. If I instead used `100%` `height`/`min-height`, the layout broke when the content was less than the page height.

The solution I found, which solved both cases, was to combine the top two answers:

```css
html, body, #mydiv {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I have a fixed 90px height navbar so i just had to change your "100vh" to "calc(100vh - 90px)"

Answer (score 28):

Try this - tested:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#right, #left {
  height: 100%;
}
```

In later versions, you can use `vh`:

```css
#right, #left {
  height: 100vh
}
```

Answer (score 27):

`100%` works differently for width and height.

When you specify `width: 100%`, it means "take up 100% of the available width from the parent element or width of the window."

When you specify `height: 100%`, it only means "take up 100% of available height from the parent element." This means if you don't specify a height at a top level element, the height of all the children will be either `0` or height of the parent, and that is why you need to set the topmost element to have a `min-height` of window height.

I always specify the body to have a min-height of 100vh and it makes positioning and calculations easy,

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

A full page is called a **'viewport'** and you can design an element according to its viewport in [CSS 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_3).

Such units are called viewport-percentage lengths and are relative to the size of the initial containing block.

- Viewport-Height is called `vh`. The complete height of a page is
  100vh.
- Viewport-Width is called `vw`. The complete height of a page is
  100vw.
- There also exist  vmin (viewport minimum length) and vmax (viewport
  maximum length).

So now, your problem can easily be solved by adding the following to your CSS:

```css
.classname-for-right-div /* You could also use an ID */ {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Here is information [about the Viewport-relative lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

Answer (score 18):

The simplest way is to do it like this.

```css
div {
    background: red;
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 16):

Add `min-height: 100%` and don't specify a height (or put it on auto). It totally did the job for me:

```css
.container{     
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #909090;
    width: 60%;
    padding: none;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

If you set the *[html](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Document_structure_elements)* and *[body_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Document_structure_elements)* height to 100%, it will cover the whole page.

And if you set any particular *[div](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements)* minimum height to 100%, so it will cover the whole window like this:

**CSS**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

div#some-div {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

**Remember**

This will only work if the div's direct parent is *body*, as percentage always inherited from the direct parent and by doing the above CSS code you are telling the *div* to inherit the height 100% from the direct parent (*body*) and make it your *min-height: 100%*.

**Another way**

Simply set the *div* height to 100vh. It means 100 viewport height.

**CSS**

```css
div#some-div {
  height: 100vh
}
```

Comment: Also note that `minHeight: 100vh` won't work - it needs to be `height: 100vh` otherwise children set to `height: 100%` won't resize

Comment: @DavidJones Have you looked at both the Question and answer correctly, I haven't used `min-height:100vh` anywhere in the answer. The question is how to make a div 100% of browser window.

Answer (score 12):

There are several methods available for setting the height of a `<div>` to 100%.

**Method (A):**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.div-left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
}
.div-right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-left"></div>
<div class="div-right"></div>
```

**Method (B) using vh:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.div-left {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  float: left;
}
.div-right {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  background: gray;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-left"></div>
<div class="div-right"></div>
```

**Method (c) using flex box:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.div-left {
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
}
.div-right {
  width: 50%;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div-left"></div>
  <div class="div-right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

**2023 Update**

The use of 100vh for setting the height of elements on mobile devices has been found to be unreliable, as browser UI may take up some of the screen size. Up until now, the only way to calculate the real height was by using JavaScript. However, with the introduction of new units in 2023, such as dvh, lhv, and svh, it is now possible to achieve dynamic height without the need for JavaScript. Google it to learn more about these units.

New code sample:

```
.yourElement {
  height: 100vh; /* fallback */
  height: 100dvh; /* dynamic viewport height */
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%; /* IMPORTANT!!! Stretches viewport to 100% */
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%; /* Minimum height for a modern browser */
    height:auto !important; /* Important rule for a modern browser */
    height:100%; /* Minimum height for Internet Explorer */
    overflow: hidden !important; /* Firefox scroll-bar */
}
```

Taken from [this page](http://www.gn-webdesign.de/css-tutorials/css-div-height-100.html).

Answer (score 11):

Try to set `height:100%` in `html` & `body`

```css
html, 
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And if you want to 2 div height same use or set the parent element `display:flex` property.

Comment: The last sentence is *incomprehensible* (use of [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)?). Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36620191/edit), please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Here is something that is not exactly like what you had in previous answers, but it could be helpful to some:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

#one {
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/newdark/qyxkk558/10/

Answer (score 8):

Block elements consume the full width of their parent, by default.

This is how they meet their design requirement, which is to stack vertically.

> [**9.4.1 Block formatting
>   contexts**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting)
>
> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other,
>   vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block.

This behavior, however, does not extend to height.

By default, most elements are the height of their content (`height: auto`).

Unlike with width, you need to specify a height if you want extra space.

Therefore, keep these two things in mind:

- unless you want full width, you need to define the width of a block element
- unless you want content height, you need to define the height of an element

```css
.Contact {
  display: flex;     /* full width by default */
  min-height: 100vh; /* use full height of viewport, at a minimum */
}

.left {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: pink;
}

body { margin: 0; } /* remove default margins */
```

```html
<div class="Contact">
  <section class="left">
    <div class="">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="right">
    <img />
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use the "vh" unit instead of "px", which means view-port height.

```css
height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score 7):

One of the options is using CSS table. It has great browser support and even works in Internet Explorer 8.

**[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ez8w5k57/)**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.left, .right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
.right {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this once...

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent_div {
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

.left_div {
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;

}

.right_div {
  float: right;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class=" parent_div">
  <div class="left_div">Left</div>
  <div class="right_div">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

[Use FlexBox CSS](http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html)

Flexbox is a perfect fit for this type of problem. While mostly known for laying out content in the horizontal direction, Flexbox actually works just as well for vertical layout problems. All you have to do is wrap the vertical sections in a flex container and choose which ones you want to expand. They’ll automatically take up all the available space in their container.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do two things, one is to set the height to 100% which you already did. Second is set the position to absolute. That should do the trick.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

[Source](http://www.snoopcode.com/css/css-units)

Comment: Outdated solution. Use `vh` instead.

Comment: Don't use `vh` if you plan to use responsive design on mobile devices.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `display: flex` and `height: 100vh`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  background: orange;
}

.right {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
```

Comment: There are already several flexbox solutions posted, including one with this exact implementation posted only 26 days before this answer.

Answer (score 5):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh; /* Height window (vh) */
}
.wrapper .left{
  width: 80%; /* Width optional, but recommended */
}
.wrapper .right{
  width: 20%; /* Width optional, but recommended */
  background-color: #DD1F26;
}
```

```html
<!--
vw: hundredths of the viewport width.
vh: hundredths of the viewport height.
vmin: hundredths of whichever is smaller, the viewport width or height.
vmax: hundredths of whichever is larger, the viewport width or height.
-->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible misspelling: `widht` (near the end)

Answer (score 5):

Actually what worked for me best was using the `vh` property.

In my React application I wanted the div to match the page high even when resized. I tried `height: 100%;`, `overflow-y: auto;`, but none of them worked when setting `height:(your percent)vh;` it worked as intended.

Note: if you are using padding, round corners, etc., make sure to subtract those values from your `vh` property percent or it adds extra height and make scroll bars appear. Here's my sample:

```css
.frame {
  background-color: rgb(33, 2, 211);
  height: 96vh;
  padding: 1% 3% 2% 3%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(212, 248, 203);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 50px 100px minmax(50px, 1fr) minmax(50px, 1fr) minmax(50px, 1fr);
}
```

Comment: By the way, you mention 'rounded corners' affecting the height of your element, I expect setting `box-sizing: border-box;` would overcome this, it means that the border size is also taken into account when calculating the size (width and height) of the element.

Answer (score 5):

Now use *height: 100vh;* for a fixed window height:

```
<style>
    .header-top {
        height: 100vh;
        background: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 10px;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .header-top ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .header-top ul li {
        padding:0px 10px;
    }
</style>

<div class="header-top">
    <div class="logo">Hello</div>
    <ul>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Contact US</li>
        <li>Login</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following CSS:

```css
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#right {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Amazingly, none of the >30 answers so far give the best solution:

```
min-height: 100vh
```

Answer (score 3):

> This stuff will resize height of content automatically according to
>   your browser. I hope this will work for you. Just try this example
>   given below.

You have to set up only `height:100%`.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.content-left {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #ddd;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#one {
  background: url(http://cloud.niklausgerber.com/1a2n2I3J1h0M/red.png) center center no-repeat scroll  #aaa;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#two {
 background: url(http://cloud.niklausgerber.com/1b0r2D2Z1y0J/dark-red.png) center center no-repeat scroll #520E24;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='content' id='one'></div>
<div class='content-left' id='two'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `position: absolute;` and jQuery, you could use

```javascript
$("#mydiv").css("height", $(document).height() + "px");
```

Comment: There is no need for JavaScript. The modern solution is to use the [CSS flex box model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17067826/1269037).

Comment: If you are using JS, I found this to be quite useful. NOTE: its besting to use this with $( window ).load(), as you will get different results being returned using F5 or CTRL+F5. Check this link for more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314058/jquery-height-returns-different-results-using-f5-or-ctrlf5

Answer (score 0):

Easiest:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  background: purple;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.fullheight {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html class="">

<body>
  <div class="fullheight">
    This is full height.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Quite complicated. The modern solution is to use the much simpler [CSS flex box model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17067826/1269037).

Comment: @DanDascalescu there is no need for using flexbox. `height:100vh;` in the CSS is just enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS to make a div 100% of the height of the browser window:

```css
display: block;
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

try using 'height: 100%' on the body too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by adding **padding** and **margin** to the body of the page:

*in css:*

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

and then retry the **width: 100%;** again and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.left-div {
  flex: 1;
  /* Other styles for left div */
}

.right-div {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: grey;
  /* Other styles for right div */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-div">
    <!-- Content for left div -->
  </div>
  <div class="right-div">
    <!-- Content for right div -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Stupidly easy solution** which **supports cross-domain** and also **supports browser re-size**.

```
<div style="height: 100vh;">
   <iframe src="..." width="100%" height="80%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Adjust the **iframe `height`** property as required (leave the `div` `height` property at 100vh).

Why 80%? In my real-world scenario I have a header inside the `div`, before the `iframe`, which consumes some vertical space - so I set the `iframe` to use 80% instead of 100% (otherwise it would be the height of the containing `div`, but start after the header, and overflow out the bottom of the `div`).

Answer (score -3):

Even though this solution is done with jQuery, I thought it may be useful for anyone doing columns to fit the screen size.

For columns starting at the top of the page, this solution is the simplest.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

div#right {
  height: 100%
}
```

For columns that are **not** starting at the top of the page (for example: if they are starting below the header).

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var column_height = $("body").height();
         column_height = column_height - 100; // 100 is the header height
         column_height = column_height + "px";
         $("#column").css("height",column_height);
    });
</script>
```

The first method applies the body height to it and the columns as well, which means that is starting_pixels + `height100%`.

The second method gets the height of page shown to the user by getting the height of the body and then subtracts the header size to know how much height is left to display the column.

Comment: I made some edits but this is a great way to get the div to be the size of the window and works dynamically well. The 100% will render only one time, so multiple screens do not work. I would add a $(window).resize(function() { as well. It looks the same minus what I added.

Comment: No need for JavaScript. The modern solution is to use the much simpler [CSS flex box model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17067826/1269037).

Comment: Adding external library like Jquery to solve a 100% CSS issue is not useful, also the same script can be done in plain javascript.