# CSS Multiple Divs set to 100% Height

Tags: css, html, height

I understand this question is redundant but I was unable to locate an answer from my searches on here and other online forums.  Here is my situation.

http://www.ci.fayetteville.nc.us/CityCommon/port/contact.html

On that page I have a 'separator' line that is to extend to the bottom of the page.  Now, I have thrown in plenty of break tags to stretch the page.  This shows that the background image (used as a footer images in a way) stretches to the bottom of the page fine.  (That image is contained within div#content.

My question is how can I additionally get my div#rightContent to stretch just the same way?

I have my html, body and container heights all specific at 100% as well as another container div called #content.  I am pretty stumped.

At the link you can view my source and hopefully point me in a good direction to achieve this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Set Div height to 100% - Pixels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366548/css-set-div-height-to-100-pixels)

Answer (score 0):

Make one background image that contains both the outer borders and the right-column divider. This technique is called "faux columns".

See: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/ and 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faux_columns

Comment: That doesn't quite work for me since the divider starts part way down the page.  The background already contains the main image which holds the primary borders and columns.

Comment: You can make it 10,000 pixels high, non-repeating and start your right column in the correct place. The image is not complex so it should compress well enough to still be small.

Comment: Wrap your main content and right side content in a container to do it and then give the new wrapper the background.

Comment: I have tried doing that but when I use the repeat-y, it repeats both up and down even after I positioned it in its specific location.  If the image would only repeat down from its placement that would be great.

@Aaron, I will give that a shot this evening.

Answer (score 0):

There are various CSS hacks to get equal column heights. The only one (IMHO) that feels 'standard' is to use display: table, but that doesn't work in IE (of course) so makes it less ideal.

As such, I find the solution that works best is a bit of JavaScript. You are already using jQuery so that'll make it even easier. Here's one example solution:

http://www.cssnewbie.com/equal-height-columns-with-jquery/