# Set separated content as same height using CSS

Tags: css, layout, height

I'm trying to make my sidebar div the same size as content div, I could set `container` div to white and would work "As I wanted" but I need to keep this small empty background at the middle of `content` and `siderbar` to look like they are separated...

I already tried something like this:
[CSS: Set Div height to 100% - Pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366548/css-set-div-height-to-100-pixels)

I spent more than an hour trying to figure it out but nothing work in here...
The only way I could do it was Javascript but that's not friendly.

Here's an example of my question:
http://jsfiddle.net/cn7cd/1/

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

it has a good recap of different methods to achieve what you are after

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use example CSS Table edited to work in IE too.
Here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/cn7cd/3/

Answer (score -2):

I dont know if you are ok to use a bit of JQuery, but if that the case, here is a possible solution

```
var cHeight = $('#content').css('height');
$("#sidebar").css('height',cHeight);
console.log($("#sidebar").css("height"));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cn7cd/2/)