# CSS Table width - 100% + minus margin

Tags: css

I've stumbled across an issue that I'm not entirely sure how to resolve.

I have a page with a number of divs, one of which contains a table but has a margin of 20px.  I need this table to 'butt' against the right-hand side of another div, which I have accomplished by using a margin of -20px - works as I'd hoped.  As this div (which covers the entire right-hand side of the page) is fluid, the table has a width of 100%.

Whilst the left-hand side of the table is where I want it, the right-hand side is now 20px short of everything else.

Is there a way I can keep the negative margin on the right, without it also moving the table 20px from the right?  I've tried a few things without success.  My table CSS is pasted below.

```
.pricetable {
    width:100%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Div width 100% minus fixed amount of pixels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651317/div-width-100-minus-fixed-amount-of-pixels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could absolutely position your table, so that it's aligned at the right.

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

There's no way to add a left margin without moving the table, because the table offset is calculated in this way: margin + padding + width = offset width.

When you set the width to be `100%`, the margin and padding cause the element to expand.

- *Padding (left) X, (right) y* + width = `over 100%`
- `over 100%` + *negative width (X+y)* = `100%`.

The first definition adds some padding at each side of the table. The second definition shifts the table to the left, because it's a negative margin.

Comment: Thanks Rob - that worked sorting out the right-hand side, but seems to create all manner of problems on the left.  I suspect I'm fighting a losing battle with this.  It did however occur to me that a simpler solution would be to add margin the the other elements to bring them inline with the table.

Comment: BTW - thanks also for the explanation, makes complete sense the way you explained it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Rob - hadn't noticed the Accept feature before.

Answer (score 14):

My solution was to wrap the table inside a div with the negative margin.

```
<div style="margin-right:-20px">
  <table style="width:100%">
     ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Had given up on using div to automatically resize and position the elements of my page. Doing a table with width 100% and then having cells occupy the height and width of the margins will actually do the job nicely to my child div.

Answer (score 7):

You can also set the width to less than 100% and set margin auto:

```
.pricetable {
    width:90%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can't believe there isn't a better solution, but at least this one has equal margin on both sides.

Answer (score 7):

it is now possible with CSS `calc`:

```
.pricetable {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Be careful: the minus operator must be enclosed by spaces - neither `100%- 20px` nor `100% -20px` will compute.

Answer (score 3):

try giving **table-layout:fixed** and see