# CSS Display Table Width Overflow

Tags: html, overflow, viewport, css

I have two elements on my page placed together in columns like articles on a newspaper page. One element is an `<aside>` tag, with the main content inside of a `<section>` tag.

The container has a 15px margin to its left that causes it to spill over the right side of the viewport when its width is set to `100%`. How can I prevent it from doing just that.

You can see the example from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/BHr5F/2/

**Note:** I know I can use the `calc()` function to accomplish this task, but given [its current browser support](http://caniuse.com/calc), and my audience, I'm not ready to rely on this function.

Comment: I didn't get it, could you elaborate?

Comment: @HashemQolami Take a look at the JSFiddle link and you can see in the result window that you have to scroll right to see all of the content. That is because of the `margin-left: 15px` and `width: 100%`. I'm trying to fit the content within the window.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Solution is to use padding-left on the .row container instead of margin-left on the content as can be seen in my updated jsfiddle:

```
div.row {
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9);
    display: table-row;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BHr5F/4/

Comment: I tried that. You can see the padding to the left of the sidebar is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625774/css-table-width-100-minus-margin) there are a lot of good answers.
My favorite is:

```
.container {
    width:90%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-left: 15px` to `body` element and remove the margin from `section.container`:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

section.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    table-layout: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #1](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/BHr5F/5/)**

You can also use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to calculate width properties include the padding and border. and remove the horizontal scrollbar:

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/BHr5F/6/)**