# HTML table full width with margin

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table:

```
<table border=1>
    <caption>This is a table.</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>Six</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I want it to be as wide as possible while still leaving a 20px margin on each side. So, I did this:

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin:20px;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

but it ends up being the width of the parent plus an extra 20px margin on the left, causing a vertical scroll bar to appear. Is there any way to make it 40px less than the parent's width without adding another element to surround it?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pvHNM/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Div width 100% minus fixed amount of pixels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651317/div-width-100-minus-fixed-amount-of-pixels)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

use calc() to calculate the intended width:

```
table {
    margin: auto;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EXS76/1/

Comment: It's easy to forget that it's now OK to use some of these new features. http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: @MichaelCordingley agreed, it doees feel strange to combine such a new CSS feature with the old school <table>

Answer (score 12):

By CSS rules, the `width` property sets the width of the content of an element, so you are requiring that 100% of the available width be allocated to the table itself *and* some additional space be allocated for margins. This inevitably causes horizontal scrolling.

As a workaround, you can wrap the table inside a `div` element and set `margin` on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a padding on the table-element. The thead, tbody and tfoot and rows within will fill up the space in the table.

```
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Seems that this does not work (any more?):
https://jsfiddle.net/kvpupvo8/1/

Answer (score 2):

I found the best answer useful, but it doesn't work in older browsers. What best suited for me was a DIV outside the table setting the margin. Then, the 100% width of the parent would be influenced by this div, not the parent element.

```
<div style="margin">
  <table style="width:100%">
  </table>
</div>
```