# How can an element have a width of "100%-50px" using only CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

Currently I am using JQuery to loop through all elements to resize them accordingly. This is what I do:

```
$('input.myinput').each(function () {
    $(this).css('width', ($(this).parent().width() - 50) + 'px');
});
```

This allows the `input` to be full width with only enough space left for my 50px `button` on its right.

This executes on window-resize. And there are about 100+ of these inputs on my site.

So are there any other ways to do this? Preferably using only CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Div width 100% minus fixed amount of pixels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651317/div-width-100-minus-fixed-amount-of-pixels)

Comment: how about widht auto and right 50px?

Comment: @Juhana, yes I've been to that Q. But If you go look at it's answers, then you'll see it solves a problem unique to that user's case. But Matijs helped out great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to hack this by adding an inner/outer div with % width and setting a negative margin px on the inside one. Otherwise there is no way to do this reliably/cross browser with CSS at this moment in time.

See [here](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/outside.html) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

<s>In the future you can use `calc()` for this… Check http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc for more info. You can use http://caniuse.com/#search=calc to check on how well it's supported.</s>

Nowadays support for `calc()` is pretty good.

```
.selector {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Does what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with one container only, but it can be done with an inner and outer.

Basically, you set a padding on the outer div, and make sure the inner div expands to 100% — which is in this case the full width of the outer container, minus it's padding. If nothing else is set, a div extends to a width of 100%, so long as it is a block element and not floated.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DhAFd/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">This is the inner div<div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    height:200px;
    padding:0 50px 0 0;
    background:#66ccff; }
.inner {
    height:100px;
    background:#ffa800; }
```