# horizontal formatting for block-level element

Tags: html, css

[image]

In the "CSS The definitive Guide", the author said "The values of these seven properties must add up to the width of the element’s containing block, which is usually the value of width for a block element’s parent". But In the following, the child element is wider than the parent.

[image]

//html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-main">
        <div class="main">This is main</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

// style

```
        .wrapper {
            width: 500px;
            padding: 30px 0;
            border: 1px solid #0066cc;
        }

        .content-main {
            padding: 0 20px;
            border: 2px solid #00CC33;
        }

        .main {
            width: 500px;
            border: 1px solid #f00;
        }
```

So I have two quesions:

1. What does the author mean for the "seven properties must add up to the width of the element’s containing block".
2. Why in my example, the  element will stick out the parent.
3. in the edit version, the seven properties add up to the width of the element' containing block seems work well. Why  the equation not apply to my example?

**EDIT VERSION**

p.wide width is 438px, the author calculate as following

**10px(left margin) + 1(left border) + 0 + 438px + 0 + 1(right border) – 50px(right margin) = 400px(parent width)**

[image]

// HTML

```
<div>
  <p class="wide">A paragraph</p>
  <p>Another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

// CSS

```
div {width: 400px; border: 3px solid black;}
p.wide {
   margin-left: 10px; width: auto; margin-right: -50px;
   border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: You can [alter box-sizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917049/set-div-outerwidth-using-css) as Mr. Alien suggested

Answer (score 5):

*What does the author mean for the "seven properties must add up to the width of the element’s containing block".*

[image]

He is teaching you [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), here, you are using `div` elements which are *block level* in nature, *block level* means they take up *entire* horizontal space by default, unlike `span` or `i` or `b` tags, which are *inline* elements.

So when you use `padding` or `border` they are added outside of the element and not inside. So for example you have an element of say 100x100 in dimension, and you add a `padding` like

```
element {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

So in the above case, your element will be 120x120 in total, because it will add up `10px` of `padding` on all four size of your element.

---

#### Explaining padding syntax

You have two different `padding` syntax, which are as follows...

`padding: 30px 0;` in `.wrapper` and `padding: 0 20px;` in `.content-main` so these aren't the same.

Both the above syntax are nothing but short hand syntax of `padding` ... The complete version looks like...

```
padding: 5px 10px 15px 20px; /*Nothing to do with your code, this is just a demo */
```

So in the above example, you have to go clock wise, so `5px` is nothing but `padding-top: 5px;`, then comes `10px` which is `right`, next is `bottom` and the last `20px` is `padding-left`.

So what when it's just two parameters defined, that means...

```
padding: 0 20px;
      --^---^---
top bottom/left right
```

So, `top` and `bottom` are set to `0` here and `right` and `left` to `20px` respectively...

---

#### Explaining the CSS

> Note: None of the element has the `height` set by you, so the screens
>   you see ahead which I've attached are *computed*. So ignore **height** in them
>   completely.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 30px 0;
    border: 1px solid #0066cc;
}
```

Here, your element is `502px` **wide**, so why? As I said that `border` will add on all four sides of the element, and hence it will add `1px` on all four sides but your `padding` is applied to `top` and `bottom` only. It's better to use tools like Firebug which will show you graphical presentation of what's going on behind the scenes.

[image]

---

Coming to the second snippet which has the following syntax

```
.content-main {
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 2px solid #00CC33;
}
```

Here, it is now adding `2px` `border` to your element but, the `padding` is now applied to `left` and `right` and nothing for `top` and `bottom` so now the computation will be

[image]

---

Coming to the last snippet which is

```
.main {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Here, just `border` is applied, but why it goes out? In technical words, why it overflows? Because you have `width` defined. So since you have `padding` set for the parent element, which is `padding: 0 20px;`, so it will nudge the child element by `20px` from the left side. I'll attach a screen of Firebug to show you why it is nudged....

[image]

*Why in my example, the element will stick out the parent.*

Because you are defining `width` of `500px` to your `.main` `div`

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9XkgC/)</kbd> *(What happens when you take out the `width`)*

---

The default box model is known as `content-box`

This can be altered by defining a new CSS3 introduced property called [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) set to `border-box` which will alter your `box-model` in such a way that it will count the `padding` and `border` *inside* the element instead of *outside*

Comment: @steveax Thanks for the `box-sizing` link, but our edits went wrong, so I rolled back so don't mind :)

Comment: Appreciate your elaborate answer. In fact, what I did not understand is that the sum of seven property of div.main element seems not equal to div.content-main width. Does it means it only be true when not explictly set width?

Comment: @jason The sentence is wrong, there is nothing to do with 7 properties, it means that they are applied to separate elements so summing them up won't make sense right? Also, `width` will stay as is... the `padding` will add up around the element. So you cannot really compare them :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien, in the "EIDT VERSION", the sum of p.wide element of seven properties is really equals to the parent. So when could use the equation, seems the equation can't work for my previous example.

Comment: @jason Take a while and read my answer, his sentence of 7 properties doesn't make sense to me :)