# CSS - Fluid column

Tags: css, fluid-layout

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/2Mtcq/.

I want the middle column to be fluid, but left and right colums - to be set width. How do I make the middle fluid? I want it to look something like:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22358199/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-31%20at%2011.00.31%20AM.png

---

```
body {
    margin:10px;
}

#header {
    width:600px;
    background-color: #f0efee;
}


#main{
    width:600px;
}
#leftcol {
    background-color: #f0efee;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    width:100px;
}
#midcol {
    background-color: #FFC;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    float:left;
}
#rightcol {
    background-color: #FCF;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    width:100px;
}

#footer {
    width:600px;
    background-color: #f0efee;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: You didn't provide us the right link to your jsfiddle

Comment: Click "Save" after you have the fiddle set up and send us that link.

Comment: oh crap, how do i get a unique ink?

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/2Mtcq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Mtcq/2/)**

Change your HTML to this one:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="leftcol">Left</div>
    <div id="rightcol">Right</div>
    <div id="midcol">Middle middle Middle middle Middle middle</div>
</div>
```

- I've put `midcol` after `left` and `right`.

And in your CSS:

- Float your `rightcol` element with `right`.
- Change the margin of `midcol` to `margin: 0 110px;` (from left and right, each `110px`: `100px` for columns, `10px` for gaps.
- Add `margin: 10px 0;` to `#main` element.
- Remove unnecessary properties.

Here you are:

```
#main {
    width:600px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

#leftcol {
    background-color: #f0efee;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}

#midcol {
    background-color: #FFC;
    margin: 0 110px;
}

#rightcol {
    background-color: #FCF;
    float: right;
    width:100px;
}
```

---

Also you can make your `#main` width to `100%` for having a full page width:

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: But that middle column isn't fluid, it still has a fixed with, only limited because of the 100px margin left and right, but e.g. if you resize the outer columns, the middle isn't matching the empty space again. See: http://jsfiddle.net/2Mtcq/5/

Comment: @BernhardPoiss It's **fluid**, but you can't see its behaviour, because the parent `#main` is `600px` width. Change it 100% and you will see its functionality. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Mtcq/6/). And thanks for your comment, I'll add it to my answer `;)`.

Comment: Ah, this does the trick, I didn't consider the outer divs width.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. I can't test in IE7 right now, any idea if it works with that too?

Comment: Heh, fluid layout with tables, back in the days, seemed much less hacky.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not supporting IE8, you can use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) on your CSS.

```
#midcol {
    background-color: #FFC;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    float:left;
    width: calc(100% - 220px);
}
```

For see browser support [click here](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
#midcol {
    min-width:100px;
    width:auto;
    background-color: #FFC;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, gives an explanation about this: [Div width 100% minus fixed amount of pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651317/div-width-100-minus-fixed-amount-of-pixels)

it explains all the details

the best solution i see is using css `calc` as stated in that link.

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2Mtcq/7/

```
#midcol {
    background-color: #FFC;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    float:left;
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 220px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 220px);
    width: calc(100% - 220px);

}
```

browser support of calc here: http://caniuse.com/calc

you could use that and as a worst case have JS fallback.