# Align a DIV to the right of a fixed width left bar

Tags: html, css-float, fluid, liquid-layout

With a fluid layout, trying to have a 200px left bar and the right div should expand width wise. When some wide content goes in (say a table with a few columns), if the browser isn't wide enough, the right div gets pushed down below the left bar.

How can I sort this?

```
#container{
    min-height:300px;
}
#leftBar{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
#content{
    float:left;
    padding:20px;
}

<div id="container"> 
 <div id="leftBar"> 
  Left bar here fixed width 200px
 </div> 
 <div id="content"> 
  Should expand to fit parent div, but any long content pushes this beneath the leftBar div
 </div> 
 <div class="clear"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In CSS, how do I get a left-side fixed-width column with a right-side table that uses the rest of the width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468038/in-css-how-do-i-get-a-left-side-fixed-width-column-with-a-right-side-table-that)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Floating DIVs inside fixed-width DIV to continue horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015809/how-to-get-floating-divs-inside-fixed-width-div-to-continue-horizontally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is here:

[In CSS, how do I get a left-side fixed-width column with a right-side table that uses the rest of the width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468038/in-css-how-do-i-get-a-left-side-fixed-width-column-with-a-right-side-table-that)