# Two divs; left should be fixed width, right should fill rest of space

Tags: css, html

I've got the following HTML code:

```
<body> 
<div id="Frame">

    <div id="Body">
        <div id="Panel">Side panel, fixed width.</div>
        <div id="Content">The rest of the content, should be dynamic width and fill up rest of space horizontally.</div>
    </div>

    <div id="Foot">
        <div>FooBar.</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so that #Panel is of a fixed width (~200 pixels) and on the left hand side, and that #Content is immediately to the right of #Panel but is of "dynamic" width and fills the rest of the space in the browser screen horizontally. I've tried a lot of different things but haven't been able to get it working -- the farthest I've gotten is to the point where #Panel is on the left and #Content is to the right of #Panel and fills of the rest of the space, but #Content starts below #Panel whereas I'd like it to start at the same vertical position.

I did find [In CSS, how do I get a left-side fixed-width column with a right-side table that uses the rest of the width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468038/in-css-how-do-i-get-a-left-side-fixed-width-column-with-a-right-side-table-that), however I wasn't able to apply it to the HTML above.

Answer (score 29):

Here's that link, applied to your code:

CSS

```
#frame   { background:pink }
#panel   { background:orange; width:200px; float:left }
#content { background:khaki; margin-left:200px }
#foot    { background:cornflowerblue }
```

HTML

```
<div id='frame'>
  <div id='body'>

    <div id='panel'>
      Side panel, fixed width.
    </div>

    <div id='content'>
      The rest of the content, should be dynamic width and fill up rest of space 
      horizontally.
    </div>

  </div><!-- End #body -->

  <div id='foot'>
    <div>FooBar.</div>
  </div>

</div><!-- End #frame -->
```

Works pretty well!  Although, IMHO, you don't need the frame or body (but I don't know the master plan). That would look like this:

```
<div id='panel'>
  Side panel, fixed width.
</div>

<div id='content'>
  The rest of the content, should be dynamic width and fill up rest of space 
  horizontally.
</div>

<div id='foot'>
  <div>FooBar.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately no matter what I did I was not able to adapt that to work properly on my site. Any way you could take a look at the site and show me what needs to be done (in CSS)? http://www.cpuforums.org

Comment: @Clueless - Had a look and it's really quite the same.  Try my example in a test HTML, break/fix some things, and you'll be able to apply it.  And, maybe you'll be able to change your username when you're done ;)