# How do I position two divs horizontally next to each other?

Tags: html, css, containers, position

On two different projects I learned two different methods of positioning two `div`s horizontally next to each other. Is one better than the other, or is it just a matter of personal taste, or maybe one is only working by coincidence?

Method one:

```css
.container,
.div1,
.div2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    DIV1
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    DIV2
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Method two:

```css
.container,
.div1,
.div2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    DIV1
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    DIV2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first one is more widely supported in older browsers, but `float` usually leads to some weird behavior (not bad, nothing that will break your design, just a little unexpected).

You'll crank away with `inline-block` only to find something broken in your design when you check some random browser later on in the lifecycle.

I usually stick with `float`, and only `float`.

**EDIT**

Revisiting this answer almost 10 years later and my recommendation now would be stick with `flexbox` and only `flexbox`.  Try out https://flexboxfroggy.com/ if you need some practice.

Comment: How do you deal with more than two divs which need to be aligned horizontally? Forexample if there are three divs? There is no `float:middle;` right?

Comment: @Zarah - unfortunately no `float: middle;` (small lol) and for three div equal-height columns, you'll need to google it, there's a lot of (complicated) approaches. Two divs is fairly straightforward: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028833/two-divs-left-should-be-fixed-width-right-should-fill-rest-of-space/4031247#4031247, basic idea is use a float div and regular div, put a margin on the regular as wide as the floated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. "basic idea is use a float div and regular div, put a margin on the regular as wide as the floated."- this makes sense. I'll Google it.

Answer (score 4):

Both are valid CSS that does not work by accident -- it depends what you need.

When using `float`s, you will need to clear them (as in the posted code); when using `inline-block`s, this is not necessary. Also, you can use `text-align` to align the `inline-block` elements, while there is no `float: middle`. You can also use the `vertical-align` property to align the boxes as you need.

As others said, there are some issues with `inline-block`, most notably that older IEs don't support it (much) on block elements (note that it works fine on inline elements, like `<span>`). You can work around that with the following hack:

```
.selector {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Float(First method). Because its support all browser and its easy to handle. Here the [**link**](http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/float-vs-inline-block) you can learn more

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the second method then there's no point in using a `DIV` if you are then turning it into a inline element. Just use a `SPAN` tag.

So if you are trying to align block level elements/tags, use the first method.

Comment: Good point, didn't think of that. Span's however always give me an issue if i want to add padding / margin...