# move fixed-margin div below left-float div when screen size is small

Tags: css, css-float

I am using the recommended approach from this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/468080/2981429 and have two divs:

```
#left-pane {
  float: "left";
  width: "300px";
}

#right-pane {
  margin-left: "300px";
}
```

the left pane takes up a fixed 300px width and the right pane always takes up 100% of the remaining space.

I want to add a "minimum width" to the right pane. When it gets below a width of around 300px I want to move it below the left pane.

When I try actually adding `min_width: 300px` to the right pane, it just extend invisibly past the boundaries of the page - it doesn't seem to be able to get below the floated left pane.

---

## **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/maxp-hover/pen/zYxedBe)**

---

[image: PHOTO DEPICTING PROBLEM]

Comment: For your layout i think it's better to use flexbox. But if i understand do you want to get the 2 divs on column when you use a small device?

Comment: @Sfili_81 yes,  correct they would be on the same column. I added a codepen to the question by the way. Thanks for your advice to use flexbox. I have not done it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox for your layout.
You can find a good point to start on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

When you use a small device, you can use a media-query to get the divs on column.

For example:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container{
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  #left,#right{
    flex: 0 1 100%;/* set the width to 100% for the 2 columns */
  }
}
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
#left {
  flex:0 1 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#right {
  flex:1 1 auto;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id='left'></div>
  <div id='right'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is mostly working. Is there any way to give the left element a fixed width and dynamic height? With this code, both its height and width seem to be fixed to 300px. I can lower the flex value, say to `0 1 150px`, but then the width is reduced as well.

Comment: Well, I just ended up using `width` and `min-width` instead of `flex` onto the left element, as shown in Matan's answer.

Comment: you can set height auto for both columns. Only the left column has a fixed width, the right column take the rest of the space.

Comment: I seem to have lost my ability to scroll on the overflow-y, but i am tired, will have to look at this more tomorrow.

Comment: Turns out the problem with overflow-y was not really related. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

that is not a `float` job. you need `flex` for this instance.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
 }

#left-pane {
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .container {
    flex-flow: column;
  }
}
```

using `flex` gives you a lot of new layout and responsive options, you can read more here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#right {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: darkred;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .parent {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #left,
  #right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id='left'></div>
  <div id='right'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: my opinion, it's not necessary to use calc for width. using flex: 1 1 auto you delegate to flex to calcualte the remaining space